# npm install vulnaribilities are different for different projects

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install, npm-audit

Why would installing the same node package on two different projects lead to two different audit results? One has no vulnerabilties, one has two.

I can edit this description with information about the projects as needed.

One project contains no other modules, one contains a load of them. They're being run on the same computer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run `npm install` it collects a description of **all** the dependencies added to your project, sends it to the registry and asks for a report of known vulnerabilities. So the reason for different output is that in the second project you do have some vulnerable dependencies.

You can run `npm audit` to see the details about vulnerable dependencies in the second project.

If you do not want `npm install` to audit dependencies, you can run it with `--no-audit` argument.